# Out of memory exception using PdfSharp in a azure webjob

Tags: azure, pdfsharp, migradoc, azure-webjobs

I'm using Azure Storage Queues to send a message to a WebJob. This WebJob then creates a PDF and stores it in a blob container. This works fine on my dev-machine. The message is received, object instantiated and PDF is created and stored in the blob storage. When I deploy the WebJob to Azure I get an Out of Memory exception at the moment it receives a message.

What are the memory limit and how do I keep below those limits?

```
 public static void HandleNewRegistration(
        [QueueInput("pdf")] Models.Registration registration,
        [BlobOutput("pdf/{Name}.txt")] TextWriter writer,
        [BlobOutput("pdf/{Name}.pdf")] Stream pdfWriter)
    {
        try
        {
            // Store received registration in database (using EF)
            AppContext db = new AppContext();
            db.Registrations.Add(registration);
            db.SaveChanges();

            // Create PDF document (nothing fancy, just a section with a paragraph)
            var pdf = CreatePdf(registration);
            var renderer = new MigraDoc.Rendering.PdfDocumentRenderer(true, PdfSharp.Pdf.PdfFontEmbedding.Always);
            renderer.Document = pdf;
            renderer.RenderDocument();
            renderer.Save(pdfWriter,true);

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            writer.WriteLine(e.Message);
            writer.WriteLine(e.StackTrace);
        }
        writer.WriteLine(registration.Name);
    }
```

Using this I end up with only a text file in my blob storage with the stack trace:

```
Out of memory.
   at System.Drawing.Graphics.FromHwndInternal(IntPtr hwnd)
   at System.Drawing.Graphics.FromHwnd(IntPtr hwnd)
   at PdfSharp.Drawing.XGraphics..ctor(Graphics gfx, XSize size, XGraphicsUnit pageUnit, XPageDirection pageDirection)
   at MigraDoc.Rendering.DocumentRenderer.PrepareDocument()
   at MigraDoc.Rendering.PdfDocumentRenderer.PrepareDocumentRenderer(Boolean prepareCompletely)
   at MigraDoc.Rendering.PdfDocumentRenderer.PrepareRenderPages()
   at MigraDoc.Rendering.PdfDocumentRenderer.RenderDocument()
   at WebJob.Program.HandleNewRegistration(Registration registration, TextWriter writer, Stream pdfWriter) in d:\Source\Workspaces\[...]\WebJob\Program.cs:line 43
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Obviously you are using the GDI+ build of MigraDoc - and there is no GDI+ on the Azure Server and `Graphics.FromHwnd()` fails.

Use the WPF build of MigraDoc and things should run fine on the Azure Server.

Comment: Thanks! That was really quick, I got my PDF now :)